# Why is Rails not keeping the locale when deleting a Stripe membership?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, locale, stripe-payments

In my multilingual Rails app I am using **[Stripe](https://stripe.com)** to charge my customers.

Creating customers and making payments works as expected.

However, when a user's `membership` gets destroyed, rather than redirecting to the user's locale, it redirects to the default locale (which is `en`).

```
# memberships_controller.rb:

class MembershipsController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def destroy
    @membership = current_user.membership
    @membership.destroy  
    flash[:success] = t('membership.flash_messages.successfully_deleted')
    redirect_to membership_path
  end

  ...

end
```

---

```
# application_controller.rb:

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :set_locale

  protected

  def set_locale
    if params[:locale]
      if I18n.available_locales.include?(params[:locale].to_sym)
        I18n.locale = session[:locale] || params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
      end
    end
  end

  def default_url_options
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end

end
```

---

```
# routes.rb:

MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do

  scope '(:locale)' do

    ...

    resource :membership, :except => [:index] 

    ...

  end

end
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

Redirecting to locales (e.g. `/de/membership`) works throughout my entire application and across about a dozen different controllers. But when deleting a Stripe membership it doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't multiple redirects happening. Do you have a redirect at `membership_path` or in your app controller for a missing membership (which you just deleted)?

Comment: Also have you implemented something like `default_url_options`? You're not passing the locale otherwise in the params of the redirect request. See this chapter: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params

Comment: Could you show your routes, please?

Comment: @Casper: Yes, I am sure there are no other redirects happening. Just checked my `MembershipsController` and `ApplicationController` again.

Comment: @Casper: Yes, I have a `default_url_options` method. I just omitted that for brevity in my original post. Just added it above, though.

Comment: @BroiSatse: Done. See above.

Comment: open console and type `app.membership_path`. Does it contain locale param?

Comment: @BroiSatse: No. I get: `=> "/membership"` But I never get any locale in there, even if I try it with other controllers.